# Dynamically add subdomain to Firebase hosting

Tags: firebase-hosting

I have an application hosted on firebase, which I'm hoping to set up so that each company using the application will log in via their own subdomain (e.g. `company-a.example.com`, `company-b.example.com`, etc.). I can do this if I go into the control panel and choose "Connect Domain" under the hosting section and set up each subdomain individually. Is there an API or some way that I can programatically connect these new subdomains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API to add subdomains to dynamic hosting, nor is there a way to do wildcard mappings.

Comment: Bummer...that's kind of a pain to deal with, but I guess I can work around it.

Comment: @jloosli Did you found the solution? I'm facing with same issue